# How to set ACR values with external identity provider

Tags: keycloak

I have configured an external identity provider (Norwegian one, Signicat, BankID), and they require “acr_value” set as query parameter to the authorize call.

This is the request parameter I would like to add: acr_values=urn:signicat:oidc:method:nbid

Example of a valid authorize URL:

> https://preprod.signicat.com/oidc/authorize?response_type=code&scope=openid+profile&client_id=<client_id>&redirect_uri=https://labs.signicat.com/redirect&state=123abc&acr_values=urn:signicat:oidc:method:nbid

The issue is that I can’t see where and how I can set it in Keycloak UI when I configuring the identity provider. I downloaded the Keycloak source to look if I found anything there, and I see it in AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider class but I don’t see how I can set that value in Keycloak UI to make it work.

In advance thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Keycloak doesnt allow such a customization as far as i know, here is some work arrounds:

1. Using a wrapper: you can set up a python wrapper (httpd/flask) that will intercept every request and change it if it concernes acr_value, by appending the missing term.
2. Using scopes: keycloak doesnt allwo you to add custom terms in authz, but you can still use classic scopes, the idea is that the content of acr_value will be stored in a scope, and since its OIDC, you could also use claims,  something like:

   https://preprod.signicat.com/oidc/authorize?response_type=code&scope=openid+profile+acr_values&client_id=<client_id>&redirect_uri=https://labs.signicat.com/redirect&state=123abc